# Как проверить, перешел ли selenium на сайт или нет?

Tags: python, selenium

Хотелось бы уточнить, я понимаю что в selenium нету response ,хочу найти ему замену, то есть к примеру: Есть база с логинами и паролями, силениум логинит их поочередно , у кого не правильный логин и пароль он не перейдет на нужную страницу. Так вот, как отобразить, что силениум не перешел на страницу?

Comment: Если вы вручную в браузере пробуете зайти с неправильным паролем, вы как узнаете, что удалось зайти и что не удалось?

Comment: Пишет не правильный логин или пароль, НО, у меня в селениуме не ссылка на авторизацию, а просто на обычную страницу, из-за этого я не могу понять, попал я туда или нет

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему в селениуме и вручную вы делаете по разному. Если правильно делать через страницу авторизации, то и в селениуме так делайте. Если правильно, как селенум, то открывайте у в браузере вручную ссылку "на обычную страницу".